# Get string value, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm trying to pass string value as a function parameter, but I need string value inside function

Here is the code:

EDIT:

```
var array = [{someValue: 5}, {someOtherValue: 10}];
var newArray = [];
var obj = {value: "someValue"};
var setValue = function(choosenValue) {

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   newArray.push({
   choosenValue: array[i].choosenValue
  });
}

}

setValue(obj.value);
```

**EDIT:**
What I want to get is newArray=[someValue : 5]; I want to create new array from array with key that is passed as parameter and chhosenValue is also value inside array, and I want it's value. It should be array of objects with same keys but different values.

Value from object will change and depends what is chosen I need to loop through array. Since choosenValue is string I can loop properly through array.

I tried with choosenValue.valueOf(), but it doesn't work. Any other idea?

I'm getting inside push() that choosenValue is undefined.

Comment: what is array in the code?are you missing anything here

Comment: What do you think `array[i].choosenValue` means? If you want to use your parameter, just use your parameter.

Comment: please provide more of your code.  where is `array` defined?

Comment: Pass choosenValue as object index: `array[i][choosenValue]`

Comment: `array[i].chosenvalue` is not defined nor can be defined because what you have in `array[i]` is not yet an object, it is `undefined`. You cannot assign properties (`choosenValue`) to undefined.

Comment: If you had already defined `newArray` and `array` somewhere in the code what is the problem?

Comment: Take a look at my edits.

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier to understand what you want if you gave an example of the expected output. Most of the time spent helping you has gone on simply trying to understand your requirements. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want your code to be doing, so I'm going to be making a lot of assumptions here.

Let's start with what you currently have in your question:

```
var array = [{someValue: 5}, {someOtherValue: 10}];
var newArray = [];
var obj = {value: "someValue"};
var setValue = function(choosenValue) {

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray.push({
            choosenValue: array[i].choosenValue
        });
    }

}

setValue(obj.value);
```

It looks like what you want to do is set a value to `newArray` based on the value of the entry of `array` with the name `choosenValue`. That is to say, for whatever value of `choosenValue`, there is to be an entry in `array` with that name.

First and foremost, that kind of logic is more typical of a Map/Dictionary datatype than it is to an Array datatype. So instead of

```
var array = [{someValue: 5}, {someOtherValue: 10}]
```

an easier and more logical construct would look like

```
var map = { someValue: 5, someOtherValue: 10 }
```

Then you can refer to the values of `map` by using

```
map.someValue
```

or with your `choosenValue` variable

```
map[choosenValue]
```

No function or looping necessary.

But let's take a look at that loop anyway. What it's doing right now is saying "For every entry in `array`, I want the value of the property `choosenValue`". Considering the objects stored in `array` consist of a single property called `someValue` in one, and `someOtherValue` in the other, you are guaranteed to get an `undefined` when you try to get `choosenValue` on either object.

If what you wanted was to obtain a list of property values from a set of objects with similar property names, what you should have would be something more like this:

```
var array = [{ someValue: 5, someOtherValue: 10 } , 
             { someValue: 6, someOtherValue: 12 }]
var newArray = [];
var setValue = function(choosenValue) {

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(array[i][choosenValue]);
    }
}
```

Now this clearly says "For each item in `array`, get me the value of the property named by `choosenValue`".

For clarity's sake I also removed `obj`, which introduced an unnecessary encapsulation<sup>1</sup>. I also didn't push objects to `newArray`. In a sense, the values of `newArray` are already a set of `choosenValue`, as that's what an array is supposed to represent: a set of logically related data of the same type. If `newArray` actually represents a set of objects, and `choosenValue` is just one of possibly many fields on each object, then

```
newArray.push({ choosenValue: array[i][choosenValue] });
```

would be appropriate.

**EDIT**

According to your edit, what you *really* want is to snatch the field, name and all, and put it in a new object. This is a bit tricky, since JavaScript (at least ECMAScript 5) doesn't like letting you set the name of a field via the value of another field. At least not during object construction. The solution is to create an empty object first, and then set a field via array notation, like so:

```
var obj = {}
obj[fieldname] = "someval"
```

With respect to your code, the loop should then look something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var temp = {}
    temp[choosenValue] = array[i][choosenValue]
    newArray.push(temp)
}
```

Not the most elegant looking loop, but it gets the job done.

<sup>1 - In general, if an object only has one field, and you're going to pull out and pass that one field, you should probably just pull the field out of its encapsulating type and use it bare. The times it's ok to keep it in an encapsulating type are if you pass the whole object in, and intend to add more
fields in the future.</sup>

Comment: I think you're on the right lines but until the OP clarifies the requirements it just guesswork. Good answer though.

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. This newArray.push({ choosenValue: array[i][choosenValue] }); works only my key has name exactly "choosenValue" not value that I got from obj "someValue". How to fix that?

Comment: Your edit works. :) Only now I have problem to push more keys with values in array. For example I want to push id with value array[i].id in new array?

Comment: I found a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare in "array" way if you want to use **dynamic key**.

```
newArray[choosenValue] = array[i][choosenValue]
```

So your code becomes:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newArray[choosenValue] = array[i][choosenValue]
}
```

But **be carefull**, because newArray is for you an array, but you want to populate it with objects by keys. So the right answer is make newArray an object.

```
var result = {}

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   result[choosenValue] = array[i][choosenValue]
}
```

**Full Example**

```
var result = [];
var array = [{hello:"hello"}, {world:"world"}, {hello:"hello2"}];
var setValue = function(value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i][value]) 
          result.push(array[i][value]);
    }
}
setValue("hello");
console.log("Result", result);
```

Comment: Also you have to initialize an object in `array[i]` such as `if (!array[i]) {array[i] = {};)`

Comment: Where should I do this? Before push()?

Comment: I'm getting empty array. :(

Comment: See my full example in the answer and tell me what don't you uderstand.

Comment: I understand, but this is not what I need. You are returning object, and I'm getting only one object, and I need array of objects. I have a lot of them.

Comment: I don't understand. Give me the final result (object or array) of what do you want to retrieve.

Comment: I want to return array. And with your example it returns new object with value of last member of array. I'm getting only one object and I need to create new array. Result should be array.

Comment: The last example returns an array.

Comment: Returns empty array. :(

Comment: @Gordana it would be a *lot* easier to understand what you want if you gave an example of the expected output. Most of the time these volunteers have spent helping you has gone on simply trying to understand your requirements.

Comment: Please, answer if the provided solution is correct.

Comment: @GordanaJekic have you tries the last example or not?!